# Hibernate 5.2 usage

Tags: java, hibernate

There seems to be several different ways to use Hibernate on the Java side of things and it's hard to find which method would qualify as the best practice and/or most up-to-date way. I prefer to not to use actual SQL statements directly and instead prefer to go with the below method, but if the code below is not the best practice method, then I'm open to what is.

So:

1. As of 5.2, in the style of the code below, what is the current way to do this? I think I've seen `EntityManager` used instead of `Session`, is one more current than the other, or are they both acceptable moving forward?
2. Is the method below preferred over having actual SQL statements?

I realize this may not be worded the best, so please let me know if it needs clarifying.

```
    public List findAllRoles() {
    try (Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<AuthRole> criteria = builder.createQuery(AuthRole.class);
        Root<AuthRole> root = criteria.from(AuthRole.class);
        criteria.select(root);
        List<AuthRole> roleList = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        return roleList;
    }
}
```

And session comes from:

```
    private static final SessionFactory SESSION_FACTORY = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
    try {
        return new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        LOG.error(e, e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are acceptable, see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html (the official guide), it starts with a good overview. EntityManager is the JPA interface and Session the native interface. JPA is portable, so if you use it you have the option to switch from Hibernate to another implementation without changing your code. I would go for that in new code just in case. The native API with Session can provide Hibernate-specific features not available in JPA, plus it is good if you are working with existing code built for Hibernate.

As for Criteria vs SQL or HQL (or JPA QL with JPA) you probably need all. Personally I find HQL to be more powerful and easy to read than Criteria. Both have the advantage of not being directly tied to the database, so when possible use Criteria or HQL instead of SQL. However, in some cases you may need SQL for better performance. Pragmatism wins.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I've seen EntityManager used instead of Session, is one more current than the other, or are they both acceptable moving forward?

EntityManager is the standard JPA API. There's not much you can do with the proprietary API that you can't do with the standard API. And if you really need to, you can always get a SessionFactory or Session from the EntityManagerFactory or EntityManager. The standard API should thus be preferred. It has less legacy baggage, and is portable across JPA implementations.

> Is the method below preferred over having actual SQL statements?

There are three standard ways of querying the database using JPA: JPQL, the criteria API, and SQL.

In general, JPQL should be preferred (IMHO). It's much more readable and  simple that the criteria API. And it's more succinct than SQL, and uses the logical entity model rather than the physical underlying relational model.

SQL is sometimes necessary when JPQL isn't powerful enough.

The criteria API is, IMO, unintuitive and it produces code that is hard to read and understand. Its usage should be restricted when you need to produce queries dynamically, based on various... criteria (hence the name).

Note that there are additional non-standard ways to generate dynamic queries (like QueryDSL), and that a lot of queries and boilerplate code can be avoided by using spring-data-jpa repositories, too (and spring or CDI in general, to simplify transaction management).